# How to add WYSIWYG editor button editor in backend block form

Tags: magento-1.9, backend, adminform, wysiwyg

when editing product there is wysiwyg button like this
[image: wysiwyg editor button]

this button will popup wysiwyg editor when you click it and the value goes to the field text with html tag, i've tried the solution in  [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/23757/how-to-add-wysiwyg-editor-button-in-phtml-form), but it didnt work at all

is there a way to add it to one of my fieldset that goes like this

```
$fieldset->addField(
            'custom_field',
            'text',
            array(
                'name'   => 'custom_field0',
                'container_id' => 'attribute-custom0',
                'placeholder' => $this->__('Custom Attribute Field'),
        ));
```

Comment: try this - https://piyushsuthar.wordpress.com/2015/07/13/add-wysiwyg-editor-in-custom-module-in-custom-module-admin/

Comment: @Idham Choudry : solved your problem from my answer?

Comment: @Piyush Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Modulename_Helper_Data' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\ourdreamparty\app\Mage.php on line 555

Comment: @IdhamChoudry create a helper file in `app/code/local/Namespace/Module/Helper/` directory

Comment: @Piyush i already have helper data

Comment: Then you may be calling a wrong helper in the code

Comment: @Piyush i fix the way i call the model method and the field showing wysiwyg editor but not what i want is a button like image above to open wysiwyg editor in pop up mode

Answer (score 2):

Try Below Code:

```
$fieldset->addField(
            'custom_field',
            'editor',
            array(
                'name'   => 'custom_field0',
                'container_id' => 'attribute-custom0',
                'placeholder' => $this->__('Custom Attribute Field'),
                'config'    => Mage::getSingleton('cms/wysiwyg_config')->getConfig(),
                'wysiwyg'   => true,
        ));
```

Comment: @the field is showing wysiwyg editor but not the way i want,  what i want  is a button like image above to open wysiwyg editor in pop up mode

Comment: pop up mode? than I think you need put jqeury for that